# Serve multiple React apps from the same server with Nginx

Tags: reactjs, nginx, nginx-location

I'm serving multiple react apps from the same server block in Nginx.I'm forwarding these routes from nginx to each react app's index.html, I've added a try_files to each location:

My nginx configuration :

```
server {
  listen 80;
  location /nest/ {
        alias /Users/harikrishnan/turbolab/nest-ui/build;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
  }
  location  /nest/dataviewer/ {
     alias /Users/harikrishnan/turbolab/dataviewer/dataviewer/build;
     try_files $uri /index.html;
}
}
```

The problem is that when I browse to `/nest/dataviewer`  it redirects to the `/nest/`. That's obviously not what is expected, since I want to have each location to forward to the `index.html` of the adequate project.

Comment: I don't think using two wildcard `~*` is a good way to go, in addition, this question should be asked on "ServerFault" (https://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The *regular expression* `(^nest/dataviewer)` does not match the URI that begins with `/nest/dataviewer`. You are missing the leading `/`.

The `location ~*  {` statement is missing any *regular expression*, I am surprised that `nginx` accepts it.

In this case, you should be using the prefix `location`, which is more efficient. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

For example:

```
location /nest/dataviewer { ... }
location / { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for your respose.Now the second app loads,but the components are not loaded.

Comment: only the index.html is loaded no project files are loaded